# How can I get access to Facebook Public Feed API?

Tags: api, feed, public

The Facebook Public Feed API webpage says "Access to the Public Feed API is restricted and usage requires prior approval by Facebook."

How can I get such an approval and whom to contact for it? Is there any other way to get access to 'live stream' of PUBLIC data from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Get in touch with a Facebook representative. Contact Facebook by phone or via one of their email forms like [this](https://www.facebook.com/business/contactus).